# @Angular no repositório global e não local para todos os projetos

Tags: angular, npm

Instalei @angular/cli assim:

**npm install -g @angular/cli**

Criei um projeto assim:

**ng new nome-projeto**

Até ai tudo bem, mas existe a possibilidade de que quando for criar um projeto com o comendo **ng new** ele não copie a pasta @Angula para local e sim ele usar a do repositório global?

Motivo da pergunta:

Um projeto limpo só com o angular tem aproximadamente 28.000 arquivos com o tamanho total aproximado de 200 MB, para fazer backup demora muito, fora que consome espaço do HD. Gostaria de unificar os pacotes que forem possíveis no repositório global e sempre que eu criar meus projetos eles vão acessar as bibliotecas de lá porque todos os projetos terão as mesmas versões das bibliotecas e seu eu atualizar uma todos os projetos serão atualizados.

===========================================================================

Executei as seguintes linhas no CMD simulando um projeto do zero.

Criei uma pasta Projetos e dentro dela fiz os comandos:

```
mkdir node_modules
echo {} >> package.json
npm i @angular/cli --save
ng new projeto1 --skip-install
```

no final apresentou a seguinte mensagem quando usei o ng new projeto1

"You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project."

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você pode criar um diretório `node_modules` entre projetos.

Da [documentação do Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

> If the module identifier passed to `require()` is not a [core](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) module, and
>   does not begin with `'/'`, `'../'`, or `'./'`, then Node.js starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds `/node_modules`, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location. Node will not append
>   `node_modules` to a path already ending in `node_modules`.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and
>   so on, until the root of the file system is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at `'/home/ry/projects/foo.js'` called
>   `require('bar.js')`, then Node.js would look in the following locations,
>   in this order:
>
> - `/home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/ry/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/home/node_modules/bar.js`
> - `/node_modules/bar.js`

Portanto, basicamente, o que você deve fazer é criar um diretório chamado `node_modules` na raiz do seu diretório de projetos, salvando nesse diretório os módulos comuns entre seus projetos:

```
meus-projetos
│   package.json    
│
└───node_modules
│   │
│   └───@angular
│       │   ...
│   
└───meu-projeto-angular-01
│   │   tsconfig.json
│   │   ...
│   │
└───meu-projeto-angular-02
│   │   tsconfig.json
│   │   ...
```

Perceba como existe apenas um arquivo `package.json` que gerencia o diretório compartilhado `node_modules`.

Aliás, Utilizando o comando

```
npm install <nome-do-pacote> --save
```

vai garantir a atualização automática da seção de dependências desse arquivo.

Comment: Seu eu usar: "npm install jquery --save" dentro da pasta do meu projeto, como ele vai incluir as ligações/dependências com os módulos que estão em outro package.json fora da pasta do meu projeto? Obs: Estou usando Visual Studio Code no Windows 10

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro você deve executar o comando dentro do diretório que contém o arquivo `package.json`, sendo que esse arquivo deve gerenciar o `node_modules` que é compartilhado entre os projetos. No exemplo que eu forneci, você deve executar esse comando na raiz do diretório `meus-projetos`

Comment: Eu fiz o seguinte:

Executei as seguintes linhas no CMD simulando um projeto do zero.

Criei uma pasta Projetos e dentro dela fiz os comandos:

mkdir node_modules
echo {} >> package.json
npm i @angular/cli --save
ng new projeto1 --skip-install

no final apresentou a seguinte mensagem quando usei o ng new projeto1

"You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project."